# ¿Como realizar una conexion a ORACLE desde PHP?

Tags: php, oracle

Buenas necesito en esta ocasión ver como realizar una conexion de mi sitio web a una base de datos ORACLE, como ya sabran que es oracle, pues en la empresa en la que me encuentro, esta base de datos se encuentra en otra máquina que distribuye todo por LAN, dicho esto, he intentado hacerlo con las funciones OCI como: `oci_connect($user, $pass, $server);` , mas no me ha funcionado porque dice que la función no está definida, por lo que investigando he visto que esta funcion está obsoleta, pero que se puede hacer de otras maneras las cuales no conozco, agradecería su ayuda de antemano...

Comment: y que tiene que ver Laravel en el título e intención de la pregunta?

Comment: Jej, pues lo pongo porque en internet me abunda esos titulos de que lo hacen con laravel y no consigo por php puro...

Answer (score 1):

Si no lo has hecho ya, añade a tu php.ini la siguiente línea:

```
oci8.connection_class = MYPHPAPP
```

Con esto debería aparecerte la función como definida, ya que no está obsoleta según http://php.net/manual/es/function.oci-connect.php.

Puede que te sirva utilizar esta guía en caso de que se te escape algo:
https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/oow10/php_db/php_db.htm

Comment: Amigo , la linea de codigo que me dices que coloque en "php.ini" debo de colocarla en un lugar en específico o en donde salen las demas ";extension=php_oci8.dll " ??

Comment: Debería aparecerte ya en tu php.ini, aunque estará comentada (precedida con un punto y coma). Borra ese punto y coma y añade el igual a MYPHPAPP. Si no te aparece no importa donde la coloques.

Un saludo y espero que te sirva.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Me sigue saliendo y ademas, no me sale de una vez en el php.ini tuve que copiar y pegarlo y todavía, subiré capture del php.ini

Comment: Ah y otra preugnta, si el servidor no es local, para conectarme a el en el tercer parametro de "oci_connect" debo escribir la direccion ip del LAN ?

Comment: En ese caso es probable que no tengas los dll activados. Necesitarás colocar en la carpeta ext de PHP los siguientes dlls: php_oci8.dll, php_oci8_11g.dll and php_oci8_12c.dll, que encontrarás dentro de tu carpeta de oci. Una vez hayas colocado dichos dll en la carpeta ext, abre tu php.ini y añade las siguientes extensiones:
`extension=php_oci8.dll extension=php_oci8_11g.dll extension=php_oci8_12c.dll`

Reinicia tu servidor y a ver si así te funciona.

Respecto a tu otra pregunta, el tercer parámetro debería ser la dirección IP donde se encuentre el servidor, como bien dices.

Comment: De los que mencionas solo tengo el "php_oci8_12c.dll", será necesario los demas??

Comment: Intenta probar con ese, depende de muchas cosas como de la versión descargada que tengas de oci o de la versión de PHP que estés usando. No soy un experto en el tema, pero intenta probar así y veamos si te funciona.